# How to stop a while loop in an imported module using a button

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, user-interface, module

I have a GUI that is used to start a listening server that i need to be able to stop using a button in the GUI. The problem is that the function in imported module can't access the calling namespace and I'm not able to pass arguments to it when I call it. I'm cracking my head on this but to no avail.

I would appreciate any tips to help me with this

Here is the code for the module, tcpServer.py

```
import socket
import threading

def start(intip):
        host = intip
        port = 5000

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6)
        s.bind((host, port))

        s.listen(5)
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
        newthread = (c, addr)
        ct = threading.Thread(target=connection, args=newthread)
        ct.run()

def connection(c, addr):
        state = "1"
        while True and state == "1": #I need to be able to break this loop using outside input
                data = c.recv(1500)
                print len(data)
                if not data:
                        break
                print "from connected user: " + str(data)
                data = str(data).upper()
                print "sending: " + str(data)
                c.send(data)
        c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        start()
```

Here is the code for the button that I'm supposed to use to stop the loop

```
class Application(Frame):

        def __init__(self, master):
          """ Initialize the Frame"""
          Frame.__init__(self,master)
          self.grid()
          self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):

            ...other widgets...

          self.button3 = Button(text = "Stop", command = lambda: tcpServer.state("0"), state = DISABLED)
          self.button3.grid(row=2, column=4)
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

EDIT: I solved the issue by including both server and client code to my GUI file which enabled me to use self.variables.

Comment: You can't reach inside other code and make it do something it's not written to do . That loop will break when it receives no more data from its socket, so the only way to make it stop would be to make the socket stop providing data.

Comment: I see. Is there a sensible way to create the loop so that it could be stopped from outside the module?

Comment: The loop would have to check for some other condition, which you could externally manipulate to cause it to end.  For instance, it could check some global flag that you would set, or it could accept a callback and check its return value, etc.  There are many ways it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

To stop a loop from outside the module, instead of while(1), you need to give while(cancelled == false). cancelled should be available in the module and accessible from other modules. The moment you change the variable cancelled to true, the loop will exit on the next iteration.

Looks like this is what you are doing in the code. If you are able to change the variable "state" to false, on the next iteration the loop should exit.